# Adding an IF Condition in WHERE Clause to Add an 'AND' only on particular occasion. In other occasion skip the 'AND' part

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to workout something like this. It's a sample code, since I'm not able to put up the whole stored procedure.

I'm taking a value from a table, while also getting `@children` as a parameter to SP. I want to run the `AND` condition only if the the value in `@children` is greater than one. Is it possible to add an `IF` condition in the `WHERE` clause within SQL Server 2008? How can I achieve the following? Logically, below is the situation that I want to achieve. If you have any questions then please let me know, so that I can provide additional information.

```
Select empId, empDesignation, empSalary, hasChildren from Employee Where empDesignation = 'Manager'

IF (@children > 2 )
{
AND hasChildren = 1
}
```

Comment: I tried to work it out using 'CASE'. but it is not working. If you guys want then i can put up the whole code tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the combined query with `AND` and `OR` operators:

```
Select empId, empDesignation, empSalary, hasChildren 
from Employee 
Where empDesignation = 'Manager' 
    AND (@children < 2 OR hasChildren = 1)
```

In this case if `@children` is 1 or less then only condition `@children < 2` is valid so condition `hasChildren = 1` is never evaluated.

In on the other hand `@children` is more than 1 then condition `@children < 2` is invalid and in this case condition `hasChildren = 1` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Using CASE can work like this:

```
SELECT 
    empId, 
    empDesignation, 
    empSalary, 
    hasChildren 
FROM Employee 
WHERE 
    empDesignation = 'Manager'
    AND (
        CASE
            WHEN @children <= 2 THEN 1
            WHEN @children > 2 AND hasChildren = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
        END 
        ) = 1
```

Or, you could do this:

```
IF @children > 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            empId, 
            empDesignation, 
            empSalary, 
            hasChildren 
        FROM Employee 
        WHERE 
            empDesignation = 'Manager'
            AND hasChildren = 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            empId, 
            empDesignation, 
            empSalary, 
            hasChildren 
        FROM Employee 
        WHERE 
            empDesignation = 'Manager'
    END
```

Comment: Currently i'am using the second solution. This case thing is really isnt working for me.. :-(